# collections api in Java

Tags: java, collections

I have a method runningTotal that returns a new ArrayList that contains a running total of the original list. In other words, the i th value in the new list should store the sum of elements 0 through i of the original list. For example, if a variable list stores the following sequence of values:

[2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 15, 20, 7]
and the following call is made:

System.out.println(runningTotal(list));
Then the variable list should store the following sequence of values:

[2, 5, 10, 14, 21, 36, 56, 63].

I have a written a method,which I know is wrong.But I am looking for a hint to solve it on my own.Here is my code.Please provide hint,do not give me entire solution.

```
    public static List<Integer> runningTotal(List<Integer> list)
    {
        List<Integer> list2=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<list2.size();i++)
            list2.add(list2.get(i)+list.get(i+1));
        return list2;
    }
```

Comment: The best thing you could do is to check out the [JavaDoc API for List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).  That's where you can read about all the methods of the List interface.  Here is what it says about `List.set()`: "_Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element..._"  Reading the documentation also suggests that your method will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1):

Your new list is empty.

You need to add things to it; you cannot set an index that does not exist in the list yet.

Comment: is the following line not doing this?

Comment: list2.set(i,list.get(i)+list.get(i+1));

Comment: @Internet No, it's trying to `set` (that is, replace) an existing slot. You need to `add`.

Comment: list2.add(i,list.get(i)+list.get(i+1));
 this line returns an error.I need some more hint please.Cannot come to the track.

Comment: @Internet - Please check out the [API documentation for List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).  There you'll see that `List.add()` only takes a single parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As you told not give full Source, i am giving you small hint  :)

- Use Generic list

> List list1=new ArrayList();

- 1st element you want to add is from second list so you have to make if condition for 1st iteration and simply add 1st element to new list directly.So it may seem like

> list2.add(list2.get(i)+list.get(i+1));

- As **SLaks** told , You cant use SET on new list, use add.

Try this code

```
public static List<Integer> runningTotal(List<Integer> list)
{
    List<Integer> list2=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int sum=0;
    for(Integer num:list){
       sum+=num;
      list2.add(sum);
    }
    return list2;
}
```

Comment: Hi,I modified the code,as you can see in the original question,getting no output.But Thanks to Prashant for the hint :)

Comment: I have edited my answer please refer that...Thanks.....sorry for giving code...you can try it to solve in different way :)